# PHP undefined index or variable

Tags: php, mysql, undefined

I have searched the whole internet saw unlimited stack posts followed by letter some tutorials and still i cant get it working but why? it keeps telling me undefined index when i use isset becomes undefined variable. Sorry my coding level is low...
Thanks in advance.

```
<form name="ghostform" action="insert.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" id="id"  />
<input type="hidden" name="eidos" value="2" id="eidos"  />
<input type="hidden" name="seidos" value="3" id="seidos"  />
<input type="hidden" name="idiotites" value="4" id="idiotites"  />
</form>

<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("cant connect to server");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
@mysql_select_db("cafemanager")or die( "Unable to select database");
$id = $_POST['id'];
$eidos = $_POST['eidos'];
$seidos = $_POST['seidos'];
$idiotites = $_POST['idiotites'];


mysql_query("INSERT INTO Current(id, eidos, specificeidos, idiothtes) VALUES('$id','$eidos','$seidos','$idiotites')");


?>
```

Comment: Which fields are undefined?

Comment: I don't see a single `isset` in here...

Comment: use `if (isset($_POST['eidos']) ) { // your DB code here }`

Comment: $id = $_POST['id'];
$eidos = $_POST['eidos'];
$seidos = $_POST['seidos'];
$idiotites = $_POST['idiotites'];

Comment: where is your form submit tag?

Comment: if i use isset then it tells me undefined variable

Comment: What is your file called? As your action is pointing to `insert.php`

Comment: -1 1'699 resluts on SO with 'PHP undefined index or variable'!

Comment: i forgot to paste the submit tag

Comment: What are you trying to check what isset?

Comment: the php code is inside insert.php

Comment: the html block is in another php file

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['id']))` you should check it like this

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cafe Manager\insert.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: eidos in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cafe Manager\insert.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: seidos in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cafe Manager\insert.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: idiotites in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cafe Manager\insert.php on line 10


the actual error/notice

Comment: i dont want just to skip error i want to pass the values into database

Comment: it seems like it doesnt find the form it doesnt take the 'id' from $_POST['id'] etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("cant connect to server");
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    mysql_select_db("cafemanager")or die( "Unable to select database");

    $id = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['id']));
    $eidos = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['eidos']));
    $seidos =mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags( $_POST['seidos']));
    $idiotites = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['idiotites']));

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Current(id, eidos, specificeidos, idiothtes) VALUES('$id','$eidos','$seidos','$idiotites')");
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" id="id"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="eidos" value="2" id="eidos"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="seidos" value="3" id="seidos"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="idiotites" value="4" id="idiotites"  />
</form>
```

But please start using mysqli not depracted mysql

Comment: the form is in index.php and the php script in in insert.php 
and as i see the problem is that it doesnt get the names/values/ids from the form its like it cant locate the form!
thnx in advance

Comment: doing it this way you don't need an extra file to insert the data in your database

Comment: thanks man somehow because it was in external source i was getting this problem!

Answer (score 0):

The reason it shows "undefined index or variable" is because PHP cannot find the variables in the $_POST array.

If this page is handling inputs from a form, make sure that the action of the form points to this page and the method of the form is set as POST.

```
<form action="urlofthispage" method="POST">
```

If this page is also used for handling other scenarios, you can simply check if variables are set in $_POST. The isset function simply checks if the variable has been set. Like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
    //then do what do u want if the variable is present
}
else
{
    //then do what do u want if the variable is not present
}
```

For the official documentation of the isset function, you can check this for reference:

https://www.php.net/isset

Answer (score 0):

## Your actual problem

You assume that PHP can get the values from your fields, which you can't..
Because you need to **submit** the values somehow to the server before PHP realizes that they are there, either do this by a submit button or send your values via javascript.

### PHP

A server side language that is not executed until you request the content from the server. Meaning that if you want these values (that are located in the clients browser) you need to send them (POST) to the server for processing everything between `<?php` and `?>`

**Try this code**

```
<form name="ghostform" action="insert.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" id="id"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="eidos" value="2" id="eidos"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="seidos" value="3" id="seidos"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="idiotites" value="4" id="idiotites"  />
    <input type="submit" value="kablamo">
</form>
```

Tested the code, and it works.
As long as you have a submit button...

### [image]

## On a side note, here's how isset works

```
function getVal($var) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$var]))
        return 'default';
    return $_POST[$var];
}
$id = getVal('id');
$eidos = getVal('eidos');
$seidos = getVal('seidos');
$idiotites = getVal('idiotites');
```

Use [isset](http://php.net/isset) to catch if the value is set or not.
And you could use a function with default values (this is just a primal example) if the value is not set. Or you could raise some form of exception before connecting to the database.

@MiQUEL's solution is neater, only reason why I'd go with a function is because it's more readable and you can perform operations before setting the value.. like this:

```
function getVal($var) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$var])) {
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("cant connect to server");

        mysql_select_db("mydb");
        $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT defaultValue FROM mytable WHERE name=" . $var), MYSQL_NUM);
        return $result[0];
    }
    return $_POST[$var];
}
```

Comment: my problem is why i cant send the value to server, i can skip the warnings with isset but the actual value of for e.g. $eidos is undefined!

Comment: @user3501188 the reason for "show them" is that you need to hit <kbk>ENTER</kbk> in order to submit these values, hidden values are OK but you somehow need to transport the values over to the server for processing because this is where PHP is executed, not on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you need a GET or a POST, I'd recommend you to especify default values in case that you don't get all values, so the function will not throw any warning, or extrange things inside the SQL sentence.

Example:

In this case i define 0 as default.

```
$id = isset($_POST["id"])?$_POST["id"]:0;
```

And also, if you are waiting for a number as a value.

```
$id = isset($_POST["id"])?intval($_POST["id"]):0;
```

If 0 is an impossible value and don't makes any sense, then you know that something has gone wrong, and you can react to it.

Answer (score 0):

how do you submit this?

and please use if(isset($_POST['name']){ // do stuffs }